# How to use Local_resources using Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

i have been developing multilingual application. there are 2 language now. Turkish and english. Everything is ok in global resources. But Local resources is not working good. Lets show you my codes. My codes global.asax and login.aspx. Also resx file as global and local.

[image]

in my login.aspx:

```
  protected void btnEng_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {


        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["language"];

        if (cookie == null) cookie = new HttpCookie("language");

        cookie.Value = "en-US";

        Response.SetCookie(cookie);

        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); 
    }

    protected void btnTurk_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["language"];

        if (cookie == null) cookie = new HttpCookie("language");

        cookie.Value = "tr-TR";

        Response.SetCookie(cookie);

        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx"); 
    }
```

**Global.asax:**

```
       protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Dil ayarları cookie'den okunuyor. 

        string lang = "tr-TR"; // Dil varsayılan olarak Türkçe 

        System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("language");

        cookie = Request.Cookies["language"];

        if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)

            lang = cookie.Value;  

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);


    }
```

Everyhing is ok. if i use global resx :

```
  <ext:TextField 
                ID="txtUsername" 
                runat="server" 
                FieldLabel="<%$ Resources: ResourceMetrics , kullanici %>"
                AllowBlank="false"
                BlankText="Your username is required."
                Text="Demo"
                AnchorHorizontal="100%"
                />
```

But if i use Local resources,

```
    <ext:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="LabelResource1" Text="vxvccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc">
```

NOT WORKING! How to use local resources resx?

Answer (score 0):

I used the global resource in my project too. it works, i never use the local ones. but i found a problem when you initialize the culture. i think you should do it in the base page with overriding the initializeCulture mothod.  in application. it will change all of the users' culture who use the site.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```